# No attribute 'RRef' when loading .ckpt files on WIndows machine?

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I generated ckpt files with Pytorch Lightning's ModelCheckpoint(save_last=True) on my cluster which uses linux.

On the cluster itself I can load them without problems, but on my Windows machine I cant and get this error:

**AttributeError: module 'torch.distributed.rpc' has no attribute 'RRef'**

I really need help, as I have a deadline in 3 hours. There has to be a way right so that my code is reproducible?

Answer (score 1):

It seems not to be possible to load the model on a windows system when it has been trained on a Linux system. The only work around I have found is install Ubuntu as a virtual machine on my windows system. This is quite easy. https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/ubuntu-2204-lts/9PN20MSR04DW